# Initialize a pointer to struct syntax

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, struct

Is there a any difference in terms of memory allocation between

```
struct_type * mystruct = new struct_type();
```

and

```
struct_type *mystruct = new struct_type[1];
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "difference in memory allocation".

Firstly, `new` and `new[]` are two independent memory allocation mechanisms, which can (and will) allocate memory with different internal layout, e.g. with different implementation-dependent household information associated with allocated memory block. It is important to remember that the first allocation has to be paired with `delete` and the second - with `delete []`. Also, for this reason, in a typical implementation the second allocation might consume more memory than the first.

Secondly, the initializer syntax `()` you used in the first allocation triggers value-initialization of the allocated object. Meanwhile, in your second allocation you supplied no initializer at all. Depending on the specifics of `struct_type` class, this can lead to significant differences in initialization. For example, if `struct_type` is defined as `struct struct_type { int x; }`, the first allocation is guaranteed to set `mystruct->x` to zero, while the second one will leave a garbage value in `mystruct->x`. You have to do `new struct_type[1]()` to eliminate this (probably unintended) difference.

Answer (score 1):

They will allocate same amount *visible/usable* of memory, namely memory required to hold one object. But the semantics are different, former is a *pointer to single object*, while latter is an *array containing one object*. And when de-allocating you should use

```
delete mystruct;
```

in first case while

```
delete []mystruct;
```

in second case.

Another difference is compiler must hold some book-keeping information about the latter case, for example it must know the number of items in the array, so that it can be deleted correctly. And of course your `structure` must have a default constructor in to be used in latter case.

Comment: _"They will allocate same amount of memory, namely memory required to hold one object"_... well, actually, no. _The pointer returned_ in each case points to the same amount of allocated memory, but in the second case the compiler can (and does in some cases -- clang++ and g++ both do) allocate the "bookkeeping information" together with the array. Other alignment-related memory might be allocated in the second case, too.

Comment: @Massa, you are right. What I meant is the *usable/visible* amount will be same. Also commented on the *book-keeping* overhead on the second case.

Answer (score 0):

The first line would create a structure object and return its address to your pointer.
The second line would create an array of 1 structure object and return the starting address of the array to your pointer

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no difference in terms of memory allocation between these two lines of code.